# Javascript Navigation Bar how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this javascript navigation bar made and I used a simple CSS to make it look and work properly but the problem is my dropdown does not work when I hover over the button and I don't know why that is.

It only works after I click 1 time on them both.

So I want when I hover with my Mouse over it to automatic drop down the block

Can anyone give me some advice?

```js
function showDropdown(idSelector) {
    document.getElementById(idSelector).classList.toggle("show");
    buildDropdown(idSelector);
}

function buildDropdown(idSelector)
{
var newLinks = new Array();
var finalHtml = '';
 if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_b')
  {
   newLinks = [
     {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
  }
  else if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_f')
  {
   newLinks = [
    {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
 }
  
   
  for (i=0; i< newLinks.length; i++) {
        finalHtml += "<a href='" + newLinks[i].linkUrl  + "' target='_blank'>"+ newLinks[i].displayText + "</a>"
  }
  
  console.log(finalHtml);
  
  document.getElementById(idSelector).innerHTML = finalHtml;
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.buildDropdown: hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<div onclick="showDropdown('home_page_dropdown_b')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_b" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<div onclick="showDropdown('home_page_dropdown_f')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_f" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_f"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your `buildDropdown` called only `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is change the `onclick` listener to `onmouseover` in your HTML:

```js
function showDropdown(idSelector) {
    document.getElementById(idSelector).classList.toggle("show");
    buildDropdown(idSelector);
}

function buildDropdown(idSelector)
{
var newLinks = new Array();
var finalHtml = '';
 if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_b')
  {
   newLinks = [
     {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
  }
  else if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_f')
  {
   newLinks = [
    {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
 }
  
   
  for (i=0; i< newLinks.length; i++) {
        finalHtml += "<a href='" + newLinks[i].linkUrl  + "' target='_blank'>"+ newLinks[i].displayText + "</a>"
  }
  
  console.log(finalHtml);
  
  document.getElementById(idSelector).innerHTML = finalHtml;
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.buildDropdown: hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<div onmouseover="showDropdown('home_page_dropdown_b')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_b" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<div onmouseover="showDropdown('home_page_dropdown_f')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_f" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_f"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since we are here and I don't want to ask another question

Comment: Why does it always open me a new browser window on click?

Comment: Because of the `target='_blank'` attribute in the anchor element.

Comment: So how should I Fix it?

Comment: Remove the `target='_blank'` attribute in the anchor element.

Comment: That will make not make my nav bar work then I tried it before

Answer (score 0):

and there is anther solution

```js
var dropbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbtn");
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");

for (var k = 0; k < dropbtn.length; k++) {
    var doc = dropdowns[k];
    var notes = null;
    for (var v = 0; v < doc.childNodes.length; v++) {
        if (doc.childNodes[v].className == "dropdown-content") {
          elid = doc.childNodes[v].id;
          break;
        }
    }
    dropbtn[k].addEventListener('click', showDropdown(elid), false);
    dropbtn[k].addEventListener('mouseover', showDropdown(elid), false);
}
function showDropdown(idSelector) {
    document.getElementById(idSelector).classList.toggle("show");
    buildDropdown(idSelector);
}

function buildDropdown(idSelector)
{
var newLinks = new Array();
var finalHtml = '';
 if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_b')
  {
   newLinks = [
     {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
  }
  else if(idSelector === 'home_page_dropdown_f')
  {
   newLinks = [
    {displayText:"Camasi", linkUrl: "#"},
     {displayText:"Pantaloni", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Bluze", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Blugi", linkUrl: "#"},
      {displayText:"Tricouri", linkUrl: "#"}
    ];
 }
  
   
  for (i=0; i< newLinks.length; i++) {
        finalHtml += "<a href='" + newLinks[i].linkUrl  + "' target='_blank'>"+ newLinks[i].displayText + "</a>"
  }
  
  console.log(finalHtml);
  
  document.getElementById(idSelector).innerHTML = finalHtml;
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.buildDropdown: hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<div  class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_b" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
  <div id="home_page_dropdown_f" class="dropdown-content">
    <div id="home_page_nav_menu_f"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```